# How to add the current id to another table in ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby-on-rails and have a probably pretty stupid question:

I have a ruby-on-rails-model for a book-list. On the "show"-page I have a button which should take the current id and create a new entry in another table where this id is saved as an integer.

Example:
I am on the page /titles/4 and want a new entry with the value 4 in the title_id field to be created in the table list.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new controller with the `create` action and the associated routing.

Then you can use your route in button and pass `current_id` to the new controller in params.

I will use `books` as this second table name for this example.

First, you need to set up routes for `books` resource:

`resources :books, only: :create`

Unless you plan to add other action in `BooksController` its good practice to list in your `routes.rb` only the one you are using.

Next, you need a `BooksController` with `create` action, similar to the one you created for `titles` it might look somewhat like this:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # code to create a new book using provided params
  end
end
```

Last but not least you need a button from `/titles/4` site which will lead to your new `BooksController` via proper route:

```
<%= button_to "Add book", books_path(title_id: @title.id, method: :post) %>
```

Breaking it down:

- `Add book` is just the name of a button displayed to the user
- `books_path` is a path generated automatically by rails from your `routes.rb` file. You can look up your current routes by typing `rails routes` in the terminal while in the project directory.
- `title_id` is a key under which it will be passed to our `BooksController` you can pick it up there to create a new book
- `@title.id` I suppose that in current view you have access to such instance variable and can pick up its id value thanks to this call - if not pass it in `show` action of `TitlesController`
- `method: :post` leads our routing to `create` action of `BooksController`

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As the project will only be accessible on the intranet and security is not important at all for this project I decided to simply save the selected book id in a cookie as soon as the “show”-page is loaded and access it from there whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you will probably be to use [Nested Resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). If your "other table" is reviews, it would be something like:

```
resources :titles do
  resources :reviews
end
```

Your route would be:

```
/titles/4/reviews/new
```

And you could access the Title ID from the route by using `params[:title_id]`.